# Jrxml Cannot Read by Jar File

Tags: java, filesystems, jasper-reports, embedded-resource

I want to make report using Jasper , so I make .jrmxl file as resource. And I used this code  to read that .jrxml :

```
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JasperManager.loadXmlDesign(new File(".").getAbsolutePath()+ "\\report\\reportPdf.jrxml");
```

That code ran well , and the report also appears .

My problem is when I export the program into .jar file , error appears , and It says "unknown resource" in line code above.
So i am worried why this error is occuring ?

Comment: What version of Jasper Reports are you using?!?  Every JavaDoc I could find listed every single method of it as `@deprecated`!  In any case you need to gain an `URL`, get an `InputStream` for it and call [`loadXmlDesign(InputStream)`](http://www.javadocexamples.com/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperManager.html#loadXmlDesign:InputStream) (or the non-deprecated variant - see the docs).

Comment: I use jasper reports 3.7.5 , is it affect ?

Comment: Link to the JavaDocs for it, though your own compilation should show the warning.

Answer (score 1):

The report will now be an embedded resource, and not accessible by `File`.

You need to gain an `URL`, get an `InputStream` for it and call [`loadXmlDesign(InputStream)`](http://www.javadocexamples.com/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperManager.html#loadXmlDesign%3aInputStream) (or the non-deprecated variant - see the docs).